# .NET and .net core share file among projects

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

We have some .cs files in our project A that are needed in Project B.

**First question**: 
how do I share the files across projects without recreating them in the other project?

**Second question**:
if Project A is made in `.Net` and Project B is made in `.NET Core`, how can we share files without having them to recreate in both projects?

I am using C#

Comment: Why you want to share files? if you want to use classes then compile them into librarry and reuse them.

Comment: To be able to reuse projects in .net and .net core you must compile them into .NET Standard

Comment: put the related classes into a big component "class library" compile it, 
start using the ddls

Comment: Yes, we have a class library and we have a .dll for that but that all is in .net. My understanding is that we cant use that dll in .net core project, it will conflict with the build at run time. Isnt that correct?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are asking for how to add a Linked File reference to a project. If you are using Visual Studio:

1. Right-click second project (the one that does not contain the file)
2. Add > Existing Item...
3. Browse to the file you want to link in
4. Click the down arrow on the Add button and choose Add As Link

Edit: The original post did not specify whether the two projects exist within the same Visual Studio solution, or two entirely separate solutions / repositories / etc. Linked Files as I described above work for sharing files across projects within the same solution.

For projects that exist in two completely different solutions, git repos, etc, a shared common library is the best approach. Since one of the projects is a .NET Core app, the shared library should be an appropriate NETStandard library. NETStandard libraries can be referenced by both Full Framework .NET and .NET Core applications.

For more details, see:

- [.NET Standard (Microsoft Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)
- [.NET Standard Library code
  sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/net-standard)

Comment: Yes, but this will not play nice with Git. Projects need to be checked out to the same absolute or relative location.

Answer (score 0):

you create cs file in .net project and share the same file in .net core project.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\dotnetproject\somefile.cs" Link="somefile.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/